# How to get a new column with total number of rows with value mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table that looks like this

```
      Date|Col1|Col2|Col3

01-01-2016|abc |    |    |

02-01-2016|xyz |188 |    |

03-01-2016|100 |abc |155 |
```

I need to write a query that will give me a new column with total number of columns with value for each day.

```
      Date|Col1|Col2|Col3|count|

01-01-2016|abc |    |    |  1  |

02-01-2016|xyz |188 |    |  2  |

03-01-2016|100 |abc | 155|  3  |
```

In my actual data I have about 30 columns that I need to count for.

Comment: `select *,count(*) from ... group by col1,col2,col3,...,colN`

Comment: Using your code; the only value I get on count column is 1.

Comment: oh, so the 03-01-2016 gets a 3 because 3 of the columns have values? then you'd need something like `select *,(col1<>'') + (col2 <> '') + etc...`

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for the help. I think this should work. However, I have too many columns with freakishly long names so I didn't even try writing the query.


I needed something dirty and quick  to build some visualization in DOMO and the table height wasn't too big so I just exported as excel file and added count column using count if.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. A database table is not a spreadsheet. See normalization.

Comment: @Strawberry I 100% agree with you. However, it's not always possible to change the data source or sometimes not just worth it.

Comment: I've heard that, but it's not been my experience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count a specific value from multiple columns and group by values in another column... in mysql](//stackoverflow.com/q/5821517/90527)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,(IF(col1 IN (NULL,'') , 0, 1)+ IF(col2 IN (NULL,''), 0, 1)+ IF(col3 IN (NULL,''), 0, 1)) as count 
from table_name
group by date
```

The sample table:
[image]

The output:
[image]

Hope this solves!

Comment: I am not getting the output you have. If Iunderstand correctly the way you have your query it's going to count the number of rows grouped by date which will return 1 since each date only has 1 row.